# React. При подгрузке элементов при скроллинге при отсутствие записей возникает Алерт "Записей больше нет" слишком много раз

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert

React. При подгрузке элементов при скроллинге когда подгруженные записи отсутствуют, возникает Алерт "Записей больше нет" слишком много раз, только учусь реакту подскажите пожалуйста.

```
const [endOfCallsOnPage, setEndOfCallsOnPage] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {

function onScroll() {
  if (callsQueryLoading || !entries.pageInfo.hasNextPage || updateQueryLenght) {
    setEndOfCallsOnPage(true);
  }
  if (callsQueryLoading || !entries.pageInfo.hasNextPage) return;

  if (ref.current.scrollHeight - ref.current.clientHeight === Math.round(ref.current.scrollTop)) {
    onLoadMore(filter, values.direction);
  }
}
```

});

```
<Snackbar open={endOfCallsOnPage} autoHideDuration={3000} onClose={handleCloseEndOfCallsOnPage}>
    <Alert onClose={handleCloseEndOfCallsOnPage} severity="warning">
      No more records!
    </Alert>
</Snackbar>
```